# Does CloneZilla Live support UEFI Based Boot Systems?

Tags: debian, embedded-linux, legacy, uefi, debian-buster

Since clonezilla live is been used for backup and restore for various Linux Operating systems, Does it support **UEFI Based Boot systems**?

The flashed USB stick isn't been detected when I am having UEFI based Debian OS, in boot options. I assume here it doesn't support or something I need to figure out with my BIOS configuration?

Any leads appreciated.

Comment: Yes, Clonezilla supports UEFI booting.  Your problem is probably due to the way you created the USB stick.

Comment: May I know the right way to create the USB Bootable CloneZilla Stick? While formatting, whether I need to set any other default Format Type?

Note: Here My default format option was FAT32

Comment: @Sashank you can use https://rufus.ie/ when you are using Windows.